# Java regex with ^ symbol: find from position

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to find ^a{3} pattern in string, but not from beginning. From position 2

For example:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^a{3}");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher("xxaaa");
System.out.println(m.find(2));
```

It seems ^ means start of the string (not start of string from position 2)

But how to find pattern from position 2 and be sure that a{3} starts in this position

Comment: Search for at least 2 characters after the start: `"^.{2,}(a{3})"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the region in your Matcher to start at 2 without messing around with the original regex. See below:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^a{3}");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher("xxaaa");
m.region(2, m.regionEnd()); // <---- region start is now 2

System.out.println(m.find());
System.out.println(m.lookingAt());
```

See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#region-int-int-

Answer (score 1):

You might use a positive lookbehind `(?<=`:

[`(?<=^..)a{3}`](https://regex101.com/r/C6bWmi/1)

That would match:

```
(?<= # Positive lookbehind which asserts that what is before is
  ^  # Beginning of the string
  .. # Match 2 times any character
)    # Close lookbehind
a{3} # Match aaa
```

[Output Java test](http://rextester.com/PMLKB33728)

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
(?<=.)\^a{3}

(?=  # lookbehind
.    # any character
)    # close
\^a{3} # your pattern
```

See https://regex101.com/r/jTLwUp/1